# Trying to get BCNF out of this relation

Tags: database-design, normalization, table

The table is:

```
Employee (
    EID, 
    Ename, 
    PID, 
    ProjectName, 
    MID, 
    ManagerName )
```

For the functional dependencies I got:

```
EID==>(Ename)
PID==>(ProjectName)
MID==>(ManagerName)
```

and for BCNF tables I got:

```
Employee(EID,Ename)
Project(PID, ProjectName)
Manager(MID, ManagerName)
```

Is this done right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Moreover, a correct table composed by two attributes is **always** in BCNF.

In fact, if we have R(A,B):

### Proof

- If A->B but B doesn't imply A, A is key => R(A,B) is in BCNF
- If B->A but A doesn't imply B, B is key => R(A,B) is in BCNF
- If B->A and A->B, keys: {A}, {B}; => R(A,B) is in BCNF